# sql reports using pps sharepoint 2010 access denied error

Tags: service, sharepoint-2010, performancepoint

I created a sql server report using performance point services.
In the dashboard designer I’m able to see the preview of the report.
But when opening the same report in SharePoint site-> Performance point content-> display report
I’m getting access denied error .

•   The permissions granted to user / are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

I have administrator permissions to the site.

Please share the solution if you have done anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

Is the dashboard set up to log in using the service account, or is it set to use another set of credentials? In the Dashboard designer, it logs into the data source using your user credentials, but by default, it's set to use the Sharepoint proxy account's credentials after it's deployed. Check to ensure that the account running Sharepoint (or the SSRS Sharepoint site it's deployed to) have rights to browse and pull data from your source.